# C++ Does char* parameter in function cause memory leak

Tags: c++, function, parameters, memory-leaks, char

I read many things about it, does really or not cause memory leak when using char* in function parameter ? If yes how to solve it? Here's the code we are using actually:

```
CString m_StringValue;

CMS_Variant::CMS_Variant(const char* value)
{
    Init(value);
}

void CMS_Variant::Init(const char* value)
{
    m_Type = STRING_VALUE;

    m_StringValue = value;

    m_IsInitialized = true;
}

CMS_Variant& CMS_Variant::operator =(const char* value)
{
    Init(value);

    return *this;
}

CMS_Variant::operator const char*() const
{
    return GetStringValue();
}

const CString& CMS_Variant::GetStringValue() const
{
    CheckType(STRING_VALUE);

    return m_StringValue;
}

void CMS_Variant::SetCharFromString(const CString& str)
{
    if (str.IsEmpty()) //** conversion error
        throw CMS_Exception::New("Failed to convert an empty string to char", 1072);
    else
        Init(str[0]);
}
```

Comment: No, using `char *` or `const char*` in itself doesn't constitute memory leaks. Nor does this class, provided `CString` properly manages the memory it owns.

Comment: It might, but in the code that calls this class, not in the code shown. Need a [mcve] to say for sure.

Comment: Just don't use `char*` (or pointers to any types, really) to transfer ownership, i.e. the responsibility to free memory/resources.